# Aurora Postgres Global DB- how to code without using Temp tables

Tags: postgresql

my org is migrating to postgres individual instances to global database in aws. I learnt there is a writer and reader instance. Some of my Pg sql statements are using temp tables, where i store data and reuse that.

My question is , after migration, if a user is reading from the READER instance of the global db, how do i handle the use case where i had to create the temp table.

current code

```
do $$
begin
      create temp table x ( postid int);
     insert into x values (12);

   select * from tags where postid in (select postid from x);
end $$;
```

i am not clear how the new code style will be. I thought of writing a CTE. But i use my temp table in multiple places , i am not sure i can do that with CTE. something like

```
with CTE(postid)
 select postid from postl
select * from tags where postid in (select postid from cte);

select * from news where postid in (select postid from cte);
```

I understand the above is wrong, CTE can be used only One time. Just looking for ideas, on how to resolve use case.

Comment: You could use permanent tables instead of temporary ones. Just don't forget to drop them, and use names that don't collide with others' "temporary" tables.

Comment: thanks that would not do. i am guessing that hold me accountable that only user is using the process. as if this code is accessed in website by multiple user, this will have data issues.

Comment: That's why I said "use names that don't collide". For example, the result of `pg_backend_pid()` could be part of the name.